# Updating Values in one table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a query here that will return different track ids

NOTE: that I am querying this from another table.

```
 SELECT t.track_id  FROM tracks t , account_x_track axt,accounts a WHERE axt.track_id = t.track_id AND  axt.account_id = a.id AND a.id = 2
```

And then what would like I to do is All the Ids from the previous table will be used to update another table (specifically The Tracks table) since the ids that are retrieve from the previous table came from the Tracks table. I was thinking of something like this.

```
UPDATE tracks 
set visible = 3
WHERE visible in( SELECT t.track_id  FROM tracks t , account_x_track axt,accounts a WHERE axt.track_id = t.track_id AND  axt.account_id = a.id AND a.id = 2 )
```

But it doesn't seem to work. any Idea how would I process this dillema? 
Also note that the FIrst query queries the many to mnay table

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference the same table in an `UPDATE` in a subquery, use a `JOIN` instead:

```
UPDATE tracks a
JOIN   (
       SELECT axt.track_id
       FROM   account_x_track axt
       JOIN   accounts a ON axt.account_id = a.id AND a.id = 2
       ) b ON a.track_id = b.track_id
SET    a.visible = 3
```

Comment: @user962206 try running the subselect query by itself and see what it produces. It produces only the `track_id`'s contained by `account` `2`. We then join this subselect to the `tracks` table in the `UPDATE` statement on the condition that the id equals the id derived in the subselect, and thus we only update those tracks contained by account `2`.